# Differentiating iPhones and iPads on Desktop View

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, user-agent

I was wondering if there was another way for the browser to detect if the device is an iPhone or an iPad. When the user switches to desktop mode, the user agent string reports the device as a macOS Catalina. I have found a way to detect if the device is a mobile device but I can't find out if it is an iPhone or an iPad, and since we show different web components based on the device, this information becomes important.

I tried looking at javascript `screen.width property which gives the UIKit Size of the screen. This would have been a hack to identify the devices until the previous generation of devices, but the resolution of the iPhone 11 Pro exceeds that of one of the older iPads. Are there any other suggestions on detecting the devices that can be done with the browser on desktop view?

Comment: Aren't you asking for two opposite things? If your web site/page has a desktop mode that the user can switch to, you just show the desktop version; the whole point is that in this mode you do _not_ "show different web components based on the device". (But maybe I'm just not understanding what you mean by "the user switches to desktop mode".)

Comment: We provide a download to the user based on their device and this throws up the wrong device. The user sees a macOS file instead of and iOS in case they "Request Desktop Website". My current option is to just direct the user to the mobile version of the website if I notice they're on Desktop View but I wanted to explore options to show them the correct file regardless.